# AWS Cloudwatch alarm not returning to OK state even though data looks fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm creating new cloudwatch alarms and while monitoring them some will into alarm for missing data or data breaching the threshold, but will never return to OK even though the metric data looks good. We have one alar that went into alarm state because of missing data.

The alarm has been configured to alarm when a 5 out of 5 data points are below a threshold of 3, with a 5 minute period. The graph shows that the data is being emitted and each data point from the last 7 or so points have been above the 3 threshold. Anyone have any ideas why the alarm hasn't reverted back to the OK state yet?

I'm tracking Allowed Requests from a WebACL. Looking at the average every 5 minutes. I can see the metric on the graph and all the data points look good.

Comment: What is the metric you are tracking? Please let us know the service and the metric (eg SQS Messages In Flight, or EC2 CPU Utilization) You can edit your question to add more details

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking closely it seems like the Unit: "Count" metric was causing the alarms to get stuck in the alarm state. Once I removed that metric (created alarms through a cloudformation template) alarms went back to normal.

Comment: Had the same problem ,was skeptical; this worked for me!

Comment: Wow, I'm really annoying how long I spent on this problem.  This worked great, thanks for the tip!